# Update Mongoose model object's array item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have not been able to figure this out. This is the model I am working with:

```
var Groceries = new Schema({
     name : {type : String, required : true}
     items : {type : Array, required : true}
});
```

The `items` are just an `Array` of `Strings`. An example object would look like this:

```
name : "Shopping List"
items : ["Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges"]
```

Now, I am going to be getting a POST request with three things:

1. The `name` of a shopping list
2. An `index` of the item I am to replace
3. The new `item` that will replace the existing one.

An example payload is:

```
{
     "name" : "Shopping List",
     "replacementIndex" : "2",
     "newItem" : "Cereal"
}
```

I want to be able to look up the appropriate list, by name, and then replace the value at the `replacementIndex` with what is given in `newItem`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the update query dynamically from the payload. In mongo shell, the following demonstration shows how you can take this approach:

```
// populate a test collection
db.test.insert({name : "Shopping List", items : ["Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges"]})

// dynamically create the query
var payload = {
    "name" : "Shopping List",
    "replacementIndex" : "2",
    "newItem" : "Cereal"
};
var query = {},
    update = {"$set": {}};
query["name"] = payload.name;
query["items."+payload.replacementIndex] = { "$exists": true }; // query = {"name": "Shopping List", "items.2": { "$exists": true }}
update["$set"]["items."+payload.replacementIndex] = payload.newItem; // update = {"$set": { "items.2": "Cereal" }}

// update collection
db.test.update(query, update);
```

In the above, you are querying the collection for documents that have the `name` attribute value "Shopping List" and whose `items` array have an element that 
has an index 2. If the document is found then replace the array element with the specified value using the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator.

The Mongoose implementation trivially follows:

```
var query = {},
    update = {"$set": {}};
query["name"] = payload.name;
query["items."+payload.replacementIndex] = { "$exists": true }; // query = {"name": "Shopping List", "items.2": { "$exists": true }}
update["$set"]["items."+payload.replacementIndex] = payload.newItem; // update = {"$set": { "items.2": "Cereal" }}

Model.update(query, update, function(err, result){
    if (err) { /* Handle err */ }
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know that $exists existed. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: @AshBhatnagar LOL! `$exists` exists :)